# Sonata Media Bundle and constraints

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I'm using SonataMediaBundle so my users can associate images to products.

The thing is, if they try to upload a file bigger than upload_max_filesize it throws an exception. I tried using Symfony's constraints but it doesn't work. It doesn't even take that constraint in account, as it doesn't fire if I try to upload a file bigger than maxSize and smaller than upload_max_filesize

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @Assert\Image(
 *     maxSize="2M"
 * )
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media")
 */
protected $image;
```

Surely, there must be a way to achieve such a basic thing?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting `upload_max_filesize` in `php.ini`? [More instructions](https://drupal.org/node/125252).

Comment: I could give a bigger value to upload_max_filesize, yes, but this is no solution because in one app, you may want to let the user upload files up to 2MB and in another one, maybe, up to 5MB. Furthermore, this won't solve the issue with the library throwing an exception if this limit is met